# Selecting unique values in attribute table in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, sql, query, filter

I'm moving my data from Python to ArcGIS Pro because they have spatial features. The data is a table, in excel, with X, Y coordinates and several attributes, but no geometry (no shapes). I have introduced in Arcgis Pro, as points.
I want to create a query or filter to show only the first value (unique) in a column from the attribute table. For example, I have one column with names that can repeat: `"Name1"`, `"Name1"`, `"Name1"`, `"Name2"`, `"Name2"`, `"Name2"`, `"Name3"`, `"Name3"`. I want to select only one row for each name, the unique or first values for the entire attribute table, by filtering in the 'Name' column.

In SQL I would try the 'Distinct' function, but there is no distinct function in Arcgis Pro...

In Python with Pandas, I would do:

```py
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name'], keep='first', inplace=True).
```

How can I do that in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: How exactly do you want to apply this query or filter?  Do you want to select rows in a table view that is opened?  Do you just want to print out the results to a console somewhere?

Comment: @bixb0012 I want to show in the map only the select points (unique or first values in the table), like when we go to the properties and make a query definition.

Comment: "like when we go to the properties and make a query definition."  This statement confuses me, are you trying to make a query definition or something like a query definition.  If the former, supported SQL depends on the data store, so sharing whether this is shape file, file geodatabase, mobile geodatabase, enterprise geodatabase, etc... would be helpful.  If the latter, it gets back to my original question, where exactly is this query/filter being stored and how is it being executed?

Comment: You can use the [delete identical](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/delete-identical.htm) tools, but you could also use python and create a [spatial dataframe](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/introduction-to-the-spatially-enabled-dataframe/) and use `pd.drop_duplicates`.